# UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode byte 0xf1 in position 990: invalid continuation byte

Tags: error-handling, unicode, utf-8, syntax-error, decode

I am comparing to csv files to each other to produce the final file with fathered differences information its giving me error message. I have resaved all files to csv decoded with utf-8 and tried running - it does not work. Can someone help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your file is not in UTF-8 format. Many tools will refuse to handle data that is claimed to be UTF-8, but isn’t. I’d check first if that file is actually UTF-8 or is stored in some different encoding.

Comment: Thank you. Which tool/process would you recommend using to fix it. I sincerely appropriate every detail. Thank you again.